# How do I pick a team?

Tags: pokemon-go

I made it to level 5 in Pokemon GO, but the game didn't ask me which team I wanted to join and I am currently not affiliated with any team.

Is there something I have to do in order to pick a team, or should I have been given a chance to pick a team upon leveling up?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To join a team, you must visit a gym by tapping on it. (You don't need to be near it, just close enough to see it on the map.) Once there, it will go through a short scene and then let you pick which team you wish to join.

Comment: To be clear, you don't actually have to be at a gym. You just need to be able to tap on a gym on the map. You won't be able to battle if you're not next to it, but you will be prompted to pick a team.

Comment: And to add to @Ellesedil, you can exit the team picking process by hitting the back button on Android or simply closing the game.

Answer (score -2):

You just have to tap on a gym near you then it will show you a menu with three teams. Then just pick one.

Comment: What information does this add that isn't already stated by the two previous answers?

Answer (score -2):

So all you need to do is be near a gym and click on it. When that is done it will ask you what team you want. There are teams Valor, Mystic, and Instinct. Choose the team you wish to be on.

Comment: This does not add anything to the accepted answer